# Error usando una aplicación de java en Windows 10

Tags: java, windows10, windows7

buenas tardes acabo de hacer una migración de una computadoras de Windows 7 a 10 , las cuales ingresaban a una aplicación echa en java en su versión 1.8.0 , ahora que trato de ingresar a esta aplicación en Windows 10 con Chrome o cualquier otro navegador me marca el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya le instale el java en su versión actual a la computadora y hice la prueba pero persiste el error, mi pregunta es si instalo la misma versión de java en la que se desarrollo ya funcionaria o  que podría hacer , ya que algunas maquinas no se pudieron actualizar a 10 y siguen funcionando en 7. tenia pensado hacer una maquina virtual para que puedan ingresar , pero si hay otra opción mas sencilla me gustaría que me ayudaran

Comment: me confunde que hablas de java y de un navegador.. que tiene que ver una cosa con otra?

Comment: lo comento porque ingresan a esta aplicación por medio de un navegador , en mi caso internet explorer

Comment: pero entonces es una app web?? o que es?? java tiene el problema de que no siempre una app compilada con un jre, anda con otro.. probaste instalar el de tu app?

Comment: Buscando en google esto: `"window.navigate is not a function" Internet explorer` me ha dado este [enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e41652f-0b53-4582-b7a0-c02981944c85/windownavigate-is-not-working-in-firefox?forum=asphtmlcssjavascript).  Revísalo a ver si te sirve.